# Dropbox API error status codes

Tags: dropbox-api

I was using Dropbox API, but could not find a standard list of status error codes to respond to such as here: https://api.imgur.com/errorhandling#400

Imgur offers an awesome list. Does dropbox docs have any place like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Error Handling section of https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! Just what I was looking for! :)